# Problemas con XML en android studio

Tags: java, android, app, diseño

Hola estoy aprendiendo a usar android studio  y me surgió un problema. La cosa es quiero recrear el diseño de pantalla que hice a continuación y tenía planeado montarlo en dos linearlayout que, serian la fila marcada con un 1 y 2, para luego meter distintos elementos; ambos están a su vez dentro de un relativeLayout.

El problema que tengo es a la hora de la posición y el tamaño. La dila del primer LinearLayout la cual sale marcada en la imagen con un (2) le pongo `android:layout_height="60dp"` y el (1) tendría que ajustar la altura al (2). Ya he probado a indicar con `layout_below`.
[image]

Comment: Acostumbra agregar el layout que realizaste, para que lo podamos ver.

Answer (score 0):

No te recomendaría que uses un valor fijo para el tamaño de tus Layouts ya que quizás en un teléfono se vea bien con ese valor que agregaste pero en otros no. Lo correcto seria crear un LinearLayout padre que contenga tus otros dos LinearLayouts. Puedes ordenarlo todo usando `android:weightSum` Te muestro un ejemplo:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <!--LinearLyout 1-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="4">
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--LinearLyout 2-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Esto hará que tu Layout(1) con `android:layout_weight="4"` ocupe el mayor espacio en la pantalla y el Layout(2) `android:layout_weight="1"` ocupará solo una pequeña parte como requiere el diseño que mostraste más arriba. Ademas funciona para cualquier resolución. Te dejo un [Link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/android-layout-weight-weightsum-ramasamy-kasiviswanathan) con un ejemplo que lo hace con 3 `Buttons`. En la web hay mucha gente con este tipo de dudas con respecto a los Layouts, puedes buscar mas ejemplos o explicaciones si no te quedó claro del todo.